# Реализация стандартных библиотек

Tags: c, компилятор, ос, стандарт, библиотека

Существует много реализаций стандартной библиотеки, например, языка Си. У меня некоторая путаница. :(

1. Эти реализации создавались для определенных ОС или для определенных компиляторов?
2. Почему компилятор может работать только с одной стандартной библиотекой?

Comment: Для разных компиляторов могут быть разные реализации стандартной библиотеки. 2 - потому что стандартная библиотека стандартная :) В чем смысл подключать другую, но реализующую все те же функции, с точно таким же поведением? Т.е. технически можно при сборке указать с какими файлами линковать программу, но не понятно зачем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Каждый компилятор имеет 1-у стандартную библиотеку (причина: для другой std-либы есть другой компилятор + "вшитая" совместимость, например):

```
#include <stdio.h> // компилятор автоматически передаст линковщику необходимую часть библиотеки
```

- Каждый компилятор делается для определённого набора OS с специальной реализацией для каждой OS. Также возможно такое, что часть либы будет кросс-платформенная, а часть – нет. В таких случаях, обычно, их не кросс-платформенная реализация находится в виде вот таких файлов (не обязательно именно такие файлы с именно такими именами):

```
some.h
some.<OS>.c
    some.windows.c
    some.macos.c
    some.linux.c
    ...
```

...или их более коротких версий (например, `some.win[dows].c`).

---

Итог:

- У компилятора своя 1 std-либа
- std-либа компилятора реализуется для своего набора OS, задаваемым самим компилятором (точнее, его разработчиками)

Comment: С точки зрения потребителя правильно говорить не о компиляторе, а о дистрибутиве. Хотя в целом ситуация именно такая, как вы описали, т.е. берут сборку от разработчика, но возможны варианты. В разных дистрибутивах могут быть разные компиляторы или один и тот же, собранный разработчиками дистрибутива с разными реализациями std-либ.

Comment: @avp Здравствуйте, я тут набрёл на это. Там есть разделы Compiler и Library support. То есть библиотеки и компиляторы всё-таки как-то раздельно реализуют стандарты. Ни черта не пойму.

Comment: @sent4me у std-либ общий интерфейс, но может быть разная реализация. *«Программируйте, отталкиваясь от интерфейса, а не от реализации», – какой-то умный дядька*. Так вот. компилятор 1, но реализация std-либ разная. Это тоже самое, что зависимость "1 ко многим", где 1 – интерфейс, а многие – сама либа.

Comment: @return Пока писал очередной свой вопрос, сам все осознал.) Меня смущало то, что либы реализуют стандарт, немного заклинило. Спасибо.

Comment: @setn4me, imho `@return` все уже прояснил. Если интересно, вот пример исходников одной  из альтернативных реализаций libc ([musl](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src)) / Код написан весьма доступно, можете справляться, если станет интересно, как та или иная фича стандарта  реализуется

Comment: @avp Да нет, мне бы модельное представление в голове построить. Как я понял, стд-либы поставляются вместе с компиляторами для ОС. Но непонятно, возможно ли технически использовать другую стандартную библиотеку с этим же компилятором, (да, это бессмысленно, и меня раздражает моя дотошность, просто интересно). Ну в любом случае, чтобы это понять до конца, надо самому разработать это все. Этого я делать, конечно, не буду)

Comment: @setn4me, *"`Но непонятно, возможно ли технически использовать другую стандартную библиотеку с этим же компилятором,`"* -- можно. Например, для gcc посмотите на `-nostlib` и подобные флаги в [3.15 Options for Linking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) / (в этом случае скорее всего придется и свои startup files написать)

Answer (score 2):

> Эти реализации создавались для определенных ОС или для определенных
> компиляторов?

ответ очевиден -- некотрые да, в то время как другие, нет (они кроссплатформены).

> Почему компилятор может работать только с одной стандартной
> библиотекой?

это сильное утверждение. Вообще говоря, с какой библиотекой соберете и установите компилятор, с той и будет работать (если они окажутся друг с другом совместимы).

Кстати, не совсем понятно, что вы имеете в виду говоря о работе компилятора с библиотекой?

Тут напрашиваются 3 варианта:

1. Это библиотека, которую использует компилятор, когда сам работает, т.е. *в процессе компиляции* программы пользователя.
2. Библиотека, вызовы которой компилятор подставляет в некоторых случаях в генерируемый им код.
3. Та библиотека, функции которой вы явно вызываете из своей программы.
   (о ней программа компилятора обычно ничего не знает, что подсунете линкеру, с тем он объектники и соберет)

Answer (score 1):

Стандартная библиотека потому и стандартная, что определена в *стандарте языка*.
В нем определено, *как* выглядят функции, классы, переменные (их *интерфейс*), а также *как* они должны работать (назовем это *контракт*) - т.е. если это алгоритм - какова должна быть его сложность, если это, скажем, математическая функция - какова ее область определения, или какие действия она должна выполнять при успешном выполнении и в случае каких-то сбоев. Что именно должно быть внутри - стандарт не оговаривает. Так что, например, разработчики могут использовать некоторые нестандартные возможности своего компилятора.

Команда разработчиков имеет право в рамках указанных в стандарте ограничений работать так, как считает наиболее верным и эффективным - для данного компилятора, данной операционной системы, данной аппаратной архитектуры.

Естественно, компилятор привязан к своей библиотеке - хотя бы потому, что их разрабатывала одна команда, и с другими компиляторами вполне может быть какая-то внутренняя несовместимость, тем более что библиотеки поставляются в основном не в виде исходных текстов, а в уже скомпилированном виде, для тех или иных условий работы (разрядность, метод компоновки, отладочная информация и т.п.). Могут отличаться сами бинарные форматы. И вообще - родное :) - оно всегда лучшее и надежное решение. Грубо говоря, к кому вы будете предъявлять претензии, если другая реализация не заработает с вашим компилятором? :) Обратите внимание - сторонние библиотеки поставляются в основном либо как исходные тексты, которые вы должны компилировать своим компилятором, либо как набор бинарных библиотек для разных компиляторов/операционных систем.

*"По-моему, так". (с) Пух*

Comment: за пуха можно и плюс поставить)

Comment: всё сильно не так... тот же `mingw` работает с `msvcrt`, которая явно разрабатывается «другой командой». clang на GNU/Linux обычно работает с гнутыми glibc и это тоже два абсолютно не связаные проекты... да и тот же gcc на *nix-системах поддерживает кучу реализаций libc к которым не имеет отноения: BSD libc, uclibc, newlib, musl итд...

Comment: @Fat-Zer это не изменяет того факта, что разработчики компилятора будут юзать фишки именно той 1-й std-библиотеки

Comment: @Fat-Zer Отдельные исключения, говорят, только подтверждают правило. Вы рассказали об исключительной ситуации. Запустите VC++ с библиотекой от GCC...

Comment: @Harry, MSVC — пожалуй, единственный распространённый компилятор компилятор, который прибит гвоздями к одной libc и тут уж скорее он является исключением...

Comment: Mingw разрабатывался так специально, я же об общем случае. И вообще, одно слово "из распространенных" вносит полную сумятицу в дискуссию - что считать распространенным (только клоны GNU и VC++, или и что-то другое тоже), и что является правилом... По вашему комментарию кроме GNU (который изначально заточен под массу операционок, языков, платформ), ничего не видно. Не будем о старых Borland или Watcom, хотя было бы интересно... Вот, Intel'овский компилятор будет легко работать с чужой стандартной библиотекой? А вообще, вот вы часто используете компилятор с чужой *стандартной библиотекой*? :)

Comment: @Harry, винда  далеко не эталон. И вообще, при необходимости я даже отдельные вызовы в .so менял

Comment: @avp Да сделать можно что угодно - только вот считать правилом делать все через задницу я не стал бы. Кстати, я ничуть не возражаю, если рядом будет ответ "за редким исключением MS VS, все стандартные библиотеки взаимозаменяемы". Вы такой ответ готовы написать? Если нет - то о чем мы спорим? :) Если да - то напишите...

Comment: @Harry, на сегодня «распространёнными» я бы назвал `gcc`, `clang`, `msvc` и `icc`… это исключает всякие устаревшие, «исследовательские» и  специфические (в т.ч. микроконтроллерные)… про то, часто ли используют — зависит от того, что значит «с чужой»… если это значит «разработка которой ни как не связана с компилятором», то тот же mingw всегда используются с «чужой» библиотекой… другие версии gcc — часто… clang —  почти всегда (хотя, можно ли считать BSD libc для него «родной»?)… у icc AFAIR «родной» библиотеки просто нет…  и да, intel работает и с BSD libc, и с glibc, и с msvcrt…

Comment: @Fat-Zer Чтобы закрыть дискуссию - отвечу вам, как и avp - *я ничуть не возражаю, если рядом будет ответ "за редким исключением MS VS, все стандартные библиотеки взаимозаменяемы". Вы такой ответ готовы написать? Если нет - то о чем мы спорим? :) Если да - то напишите...*

Comment: @Harry, avp тут тоже не совсем прав...  на самом деле ответ сложнее... я постараюсь что-то набросать, но обещать не могу...